# Rigorous definition of the perfect conductor in macroscopic electrodynamics

Tags: electrostatics, solid-state-physics, conductors

Zangwill (in *Modern Electrodynamics* -- most of this discussion relates to Chapters 5.1 and 5.2 if you have access to the book) defines a perfect conductor as a macropscopic model for certain matter in which the chemical energy of the electrons due to the potential of the underlying lattice is zero. Considering a situation in which there is, most generally, just an externally impressed electrostatic field $\textbf{E}_{ext}(\textbf{r})$, this leads to (i.e. it follows as a theorem that) the "typical" definition of a perfect conductor in which the total electric field $\bf{E}(\bf{r}) = \bf{0}$ ($\textbf{E}(\textbf{r}) = \textbf{E}_{ext}(\textbf{r}) + \textbf{E}_{self}(\textbf{r})$, where $\textbf{E}_{self}$ is the electric field due to the polarizable bodies)  by applying Thomson's theorem (the electrostatic energy $U_E$ of a system is minimized when the electrostatic potential $\varphi$ in the body of fixed size is constant) as follows. By definition, the potential energy of a perfect conductor is equal to its electrostatic potential energy (there is no contribution from quantum mechanics -- i.e. from the potential energy of the electrons in the lattice potential). Thus the minimum energy for the system is when the system minimizes its electrostatic potential energy, so $\varphi = const$ in the body and $\textbf{E} \equiv -\nabla \varphi=\bf{0}$ as stated.

I have a few (all related) questions about such a deduction:

1. To me, the discussion above seems to signal that a perfect conductor is one in which the electrons are free (Sommerfeld model as per Ashcroft and Mermin). Is this correct? **Edit: Per a comment below, it seems like the Sommerfeld model is necessary but not sufficient to have a perfect conductor. The point of invoking the Sommerfeld model was that it captures the notion of all electrons having zero potential energy.**
2. Zangwill then goes on to say that a body in equilibrium will seek to achieve its lowest energy and that, since we *defined* a perfect conductor as one in which the energy of the electrons due to interactions with lattice potential is zero (or, what's better, constant), then the ground state of a perfect conductor obtains when we minimize the electrostatic potential energy of the system when it experiences an external field. But why should lowest energy be the relevant potential? For example, in systems with constant pressure and temperature, the lowest Gibbs free energy state will be the final state. The volume of this thermodynamic system is constant but its not clear to me that every final macrostate has the same entropy (which seems to be what's tacitly assumed if we are saying that only energy considerations determine the ground state). Also, I don't quite know enough thermodynamics to know how to account for the constant electric field here (does it enter as a potential somehow, or has my inclusion of its effect in terms of internal energy sufficed)?
3. This calculation/reasoning seems to be sort of semiclassical, insofar as the "quantum mechanical" potential energy is computed in near-equilibrium as a suitable average sum over the energies occupied electron states etc., and then on top of this we speak of a sort of classical electrostatic energy for the charge no longer thought of as quantum but now suitably Lorentz averaged etc. Is there a resource which talks about this limit?

Comment: The equilibrium discussions assume there's a negligible temperature. So minimizing the Helmholtz free energy is just a matter of minimizing internal energy.

Comment: @ConnorBehan Thanks for the answer! Should it be obvious to me/how do you know that these discussions tacitly assume $T=0$?

Comment: The Sommerfeld model is a semi-classical conductivity model for it estimates *finite* metal conductivity and improves on the Drude model, so that the internal electric field is *not* zero.

Comment: I think you are overcomplicating the issue by bringing in QM and thermodynamics. Letting $E=0$ internally this is purely a 1st order macroscopic assumption on the E field that is never true but good enough for *engineering* purposes most of the time, and when it is not good enough then it is replaced by concepts such as skin depths and impedance boundary conditions, etc.

Comment: Of course $E=0$ is perfectly good as a mathematical model for a perfect conductor -- I'm just trying to follow Zangwill and to get a sense of which limit from solid state physics leads to the "perfect conductor". @hyportnex

Comment: @ConnorBehan Please let me know/feel free to give an answer and I'd be happy to accept.